# AngularJS/JSON: Refer to array member by value instead of index?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json

I have JSON data in the format of:

```
[  
 {
  "name": "partnerCodePrefix",
  "val": "12345",
  "inherit": true
 },
 {
  "name": "partnerCode",
  "val": "AAAAAnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn",
  "inherit": false
  }
]
```

Currently, I am accessing this data in my UI with array index numbers, like:

```
        <tr class="inherited">
            <td>
              <label>Partner Code Prefix</label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="checkbox" name="partnerCodePrefixInherit" id="" ng-model="mob.mobData[1].inherit">
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" ng-model="mob.mobData[1].val" ng-disabled="mob.mobData[1].inherit">
            </td>
          </tr>
```

So, in this example I get the `val` of `partnerCodePrefix` with

```
ng-model="mob.mobData[1].val"
```

However, I would rather get the `val` with the array member's `name` value rather than its index, so I can more easily re-order rows if needed.

Something like:

```
 ng-model="mob.mobData['name==partnerCodePrefix'].val"
```

Is there any way to do this?  What's the correct syntax?

Comment: There is no syntax/way to do  `mob.mobData['name==partnerCodePrefix'].val`. Have you considered creating a different object mapped from this to suit your need. You could just create map with key being the value of name. You can also use lodash.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can have a function that takes the value has the parameter and returns the index of the array when the name is equal to the parameter like

mob.mobData[ returnIndex(str)].Val